# SQL output rendering renamed duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with data similar to the following:

```
id  p_id   process
300 1      initial
300 2      stage_beta
300 3      conversion
300 4      render
300 5      stage_beta
300 6      conversion
300 7      render
300 8      finish
```

I would like to generate a SQL query such that my output would modify the duplicate process as a new process.

```
id  p_id    process
300 1   initial
300 2   stage_beta
300 3   conversion
300 4   render
300 5   stage_beta_new
300 6   conversion_new
300 7   render_new
300 8   finish
```

I have tried using variations on the following join, but I am missing something:

```
SELECT id,
       process,
       process_id
FROM process_view

JOIN (SELECT id, 
             process_id,
             (CASE WHEN process = "stage_beta" then "stage_beta_new"
                   WHEN process = "conversion" then "conversion_new"
                   WHEN process = "render" then "render_new"
              ELSE name
              END) as name
      FROM process_view) AS process2 on process.id = process2.id
```

The end result just renames all of the fields, but does not retain the initial process or allow for if the process repeats a third time.

Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happen if you have three `"conversion"`?? would you have `"conversion_new_new"` ??

Answer (score 0):

First assign an number to each repeated process:

```
 SELECT id,  p_id, process,
        row_number() over (partition by id, process order by p_id) as rn
 FROM YourTable
```

Now you can assign new to all beside the first one, or assign the number:

```
SELECT id,  p_id,
       CASE WHEN rn > 1 
            THEN CONCAT(process, '_new')
            ELSE process
       END as process,
       CONCAT(process, '_' , rn) as process2
FROM (           
     SELECT id,  p_id, process,
            row_number() over (partition by id, process order by p_id) as rn
     FROM YourTable
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a window function as

```
 SELECT *,
        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Process ORDER BY ID) = 1
             THEN Process
             ELSE CONCAT(Process, '_new') END
 FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

With EXISTS:

```
select p.id, p.p_id,
  concat(
    p.process,
    case 
      when exists (
        select 1 from process_view
        where id = p.id and process = p.process and p_id < p.p_id
      ) then '_new' 
      else ''
    end
  ) process
from process_view p
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8MtwpFAxXi8npdk26eaf4v/0).
Results:

```
| id  | p_id | process        |
| --- | ---- | -------------- |
| 300 | 1    | initial        |
| 300 | 2    | stage_beta     |
| 300 | 3    | conversion     |
| 300 | 4    | render         |
| 300 | 5    | stage_beta_new |
| 300 | 6    | conversion_new |
| 300 | 7    | render_new     |
| 300 | 8    | finish         |
```